# Reactor Kafka: Consumption is stopped with out of order commit enabled (maxDeferredCommits>0)

Tags: spring-kafka, reactor-kafka

We use reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate to receive messages, then Acknowledge the offset after processing the message. We enabled the out of order commit (maxDeferredCommits=250) and noticed the consumer paused infinitely in certain situations.
The events pattern are:

1. There might be some network glitch or kafka server maintenance. RetriableCommitFailedException triggered
2. Consumer pause with “Paused - commits are retrying”
3. Consumer “Resume” and “Emitting records”. But there is no more “Async committing” log. (no message acknowledgement exception identify)
4. After some “Emitting records” logs, Consumer pause with “Paused - too many deferred commits”
5. No more “ConsumerEventLoop” log
6. Rebalance fixes the issue. (We have 3 consumers deployed on 3 hosts, remove 1 host fix the issue)

```
reactor-kafka-1.3.13.jar
logging:
 level:
   reactor:
     kafka:
       receiver: DEBUG
maxDeferredCommits: 250
ConsumerConfig
auto.commit.interval.ms = 1000
auto.offset.reset = earliest
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
enable.auto.commit = false
heartbeat.interval.ms = 1000
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000     
max.poll.records = 500
request.timeout.ms = 30000
session.timeout.ms = 10000
```

Logs:

```
11/24/22 6:50:06.386 AM DEBUG r.k.r.internals.ConsumerEventLoop Async committing: {
test-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=12206778, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, 
test-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=12253822, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}
test-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=12257066, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}
test-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=12265134, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}

No more “Async committing” after this

11/24/22 6:50:06.451 AM WARN r.k.r.internals.ConsumerEventLoop Commit failed with org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RetriableCommitFailedException: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing the latest consumed offsets. Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null

11/24/22 6:50:06.452 AM WARN r.k.r.internals.ConsumerEventLoop Commit failed with exceptionorg.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RetriableCommitFailedException: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing the latest consumed offsets., retries remaining 99
…
11/24/22 6:50:06.452 AM WARN r.k.r.internals.Commit failed with exceptionorg.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RetriableCommitFailedException: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing the latest consumed offsets., retries remaining 93

11/24/22 6:50:06.486 DEBUG r.k.r.internals.ConsumerEventLoop -Paused - commits are retrying
11/24/22 6:50:06.987 DEBUG r.k.r.internals.ConsumerEventLoop -Resumed
11/24/22 6:50:07.387 DEBUG r.k.r.internals.ConsumerEventLoop -Emitting 1 records, requested now 1
11/24/22 6:50:07.387 DEBUG r.k.r.internals.ConsumerEventLoop -onRequest.toAdd 1, paused false
…

11/24/22 6:51:05.248 DEBUG r.k.r.internals.ConsumerEventLoop -Paused - too many deferred commits
11/24/22 6:51:05.248 DEBUG r.k.r.internals.ConsumerEventLoop -Consumer woken

No more “ConsumerEventLoop” log after this until rebalance
```

code detail:

```
consumeMessge() {

ReceiverOptions basicReceiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.create(
   consumerProperties)
   .maxDeferredCommits(250)
   .commitInterval(Duration.ofMillis(commitInterval))
   .subscription(topics);

reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate=new ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<>(basicReceiverOptions);

 return reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate
     .receive()
     .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
     .flatMap(x -> Mono.just(x)
              .delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(500),10))
     .flatMap(receiverRecord ->
            //process the record
             messageServiceImpl.process(receiverRecord)
             .doFinally(x -> {
               //ack offset
               log.info("MessageConsumer ACK offset={} ", receiverRecord.offset());
               receiverRecord.receiverOffset().acknowledge();
             })
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
     )
     .....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be a bug; please open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Issue opened https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/issues/304. Thanks!

Comment: @Gary, Same behaviour is with Spring kafka-AsyncAcks, is there way we can add timeout for it or any other solution?

Comment: Don’t ask questions about different projects in comments. Are you using the latest 2.8, 2.9, 3.0 version? A problem was fixed a couple of months ago https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2410 If it is still a problem ask a new question with much more information.